# Why are my divs overlapping when im resizing the browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a simple login form and it looks fine until I resize my browser. I'm working with three `<div>` elements here; `center`, `center2` and `center3`. They are all wrapped up in `main`. `bgpc` is just the background picture.

As soon as I resize the browser the 3 center divs overlap each other and nothing stays in its place.

I already tried setting `position` to `absolute` or `relative` in the wrapper and in the three center divs but nothing seems to work.

```css
#bgpc {
  float: bottom;
  height: 100%;
  background-position: absolute;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: -1;
  filter: blur(3px) brightness(50%);
  background-image: url("../images/background1.gif");
  /*background-image: url("../images/home_alt.png");*/
  /*background-image: url('../images/backTest.PNG');*/
}

#center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #35ada7;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 180%;
  filter: drop-shadow(8px 8px 10px gray) opacity(75%);
  color: white;
  display: block;
}

#center2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 80%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  filter: drop-shadow(8px 8px 10px gray) opacity(75%);
  display: block;
}

#center3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 62%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  filter: drop-shadow(8px 8px 10px gray) opacity(75%);
  display: block;
}

#main {
  float: bottom;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="bgpc"></div>
  <div id="center">
    <h1>MyCalc</h1>
    <b>Si</b>mple <b>Cal</b>culator
  </div>
  <div id="center3">
    <center>
      <h1 style="color: white">Log in to use the<br> Calculator</h1>
    </center>
  </div>
  <div id="center2">
    <form method="post" action="testAspx.aspx" class="login-form">
      <div class="input-container">
        <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
        <input type="email" id="userName" class="input" name="email" style="background-color: transparent; color: white" placeholder="Username" />
      </div>
      <div class="input-container">
        <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
        <input type="password" id="loginPassword" class="input" name="password" style="background-color: transparent; color: white" placeholder="Password" />
        <i id="show-password" class="fa fa-eye"></i>
      </div>
      <input id="submit" type="button" name="login" value="Login" onclick="Schleife(0)" class="button" />
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is your `position: absolute`. When you use that, the elements are taken out of the document flow (e.g. they no longer interact with other elements on the page). So they will always overlap. Also, the `<center>` tag is a deprecated tag and should not be used.

Comment: The problem is because you've used `position: absolute` along with `%` values for the top/left. If you want to prevent the elements from overlapping, put the `position: absolute` and `top`/`left` settings on a *single* parent element only, and then align the three divs with each other using margin/padding

Comment: Your main issue is about position:absolute being generally hard to manage, but it's worth mentioning that you can target specific screen sizes with responsive [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should nest your elements like so

```
  -- center
     --center-3
     --center-2
```

and remove the absolute positioning on center-2 and 3 letting the parent handle the positioning

If i were to simplify it after that id just inline the content and remove centre-2 and -3 and use flex box for centering.

```css
.center {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 300px;
  box-shadow: 9px 8px 10px 0px rgba(158, 155, 158, 1);
  padding: 5px 0 10px;
  flex: 1;
}

.column {
  padding: 0 16px;
}

.titles {
  background-color: #35ada7;
  color: white;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="center">
    <div class="titles column">
      <h1>MyCalc</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <p>Simple Calculator</p>

      <h1>Log in to use the<br> Calculator</h1>
      <form method="post" action="testAspx.aspx" class="login-form">
        <div class="input-container">
          <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
          <input type="email" id="userName" class="input" name="email" style="background-color: transparent;" placeholder="Username" />
        </div>
        <div class="input-container">
          <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
          <input type="password" id="loginPassword" class="input" name="password" style="background-color: transparent;" placeholder="Password" />
          <i id="show-password" class="fa fa-eye"></i>
        </div>
        <input id="submit" type="button" name="login" value="Login" onclick="Schleife(0)" class="button" />
      </form>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```